# How to add rows to calendar in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I can't figure out how to automatically add new rows and columns to this calendar. I cannot use jQuery or anything fancy for this task. The changes must be made to .js only. Here are the hints I was given:

1. In the onload event handler, write the code that loops through the days of the month to create the rows for the calendar.
2. Use a tr element for each new row and td elements within the rows for the days of the months. To display the rows, add them to the innerHTML property of the calendar table, but remember that the new rows have to go after the row that’s in the HTML. Please find my code in snippets below:

Thank you!

```js
var $ = function (id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

var getMonthText = function(currentMonth) {
    if (currentMonth === 0) { return "January"; }
    else if (currentMonth === 1) { return "February"; }
    else if (currentMonth === 2) { return "March"; }
    else if (currentMonth === 3) { return "April"; }
    else if (currentMonth === 4) { return "May"; }
    else if (currentMonth === 5) { return "June"; }
    else if (currentMonth === 6) { return "July"; }
    else if (currentMonth === 7) { return "August"; }
    else if (currentMonth === 8) { return "September"; }
    else if (currentMonth === 9) { return "October"; }
    else if (currentMonth === 10) { return "November"; }
    else if (currentMonth === 11) { return "December"; }
};

var getLastDayofMonth = function(currentMonth) {
    var endOfMonth = getmonth(currentMonth);

    endOfMonth.setMonth(endOfMonth.getMonth() + 1);
    return endOfMonth.setDate(0);

};

window.onload = function () {

    // display current month and year
    actualMonth = new Date().getMonth();
    actualYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    $("month_year").textContent = getMonthText(actualMonth) + " " + actualYear;

// UPDATE 2
var newRow = document.createElement('tr');

for (var i = 1; i < endOfMonth.setDate(0); i++) 
{
    var newCell = document.createElement('td');
    newRow.appendChild(newCell);

}

document.getElementById('calendar').appendChild(newRow);
    
};
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 360px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 0 2em 1em;
}
h1 {
    color: blue;
    margin-bottom: .25em;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
    width: 3em;
    height: 3em;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0.5 0 0 0.5;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calendar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calendar.css">
    <script src="calendar.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <h1><span id="month_year">&nbsp;</span></h1>

        <table id="calendar">
            <tr><th>Sun</th><th>Mon</th><th>Tue</th><th>Wed</th><th>Thu</th><th>Fri</th><th>Sat</th></tr>
        </table>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of the large block of if-statements in getMonthText, I'd suggest maybe just using an array.

Comment: I think for this task I am 'forced' to do it this way, as I haven't done arrays yet! So how can I navigate around this limitation? My problem is at the bottom withe for loop to add new rows and columns to the calendar.

Comment: Ah ok, so basically equivalent to what you have there would be to make an array with all the month names, and then you can refer to them by their index (ie: their position in the array).  `var monthNames = ['January', 'February', 'etc...'];` Then `monthNames[0]` would be "January", `monthNames[1]` would be "February" and so on.

Comment: Thank you. What about my for loop? That's where my main question lies. I need to loop through the days of the month and add rows and columns (as explained in my question). If you could save me here, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to make use of the [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and the [node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) methods.

Use the `createElement` method to create a new `<tr>` element. Then create `<td>` elements. Append your new `<td>` elements to your new `<tr>` using the `appendChild` method, and then append your `<tr>` to the table.

e.g.

```
// outside your for loop
var newRow = document.createElement('tr');

// inside your for loop
var newCell = document.createElement('td');
newRow.appendChild(newCell);

// after your loop
document.getElementById('calendar').appendChild(newRow);
```

Comment: Thank you! I added your code my .js (check above for UPDATE 2). I think I need to use the 'i' to loop through it, but I don't know how...

Also, what about innerHTML? Do I need to use it?

Comment: You need to read up on how for loops work. I wouldn't normally advocate for using w3schools, but for you it would probably be a good start https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp. As for innerHTML, that all depends on what you are trying to do. Read the documentation on it and decide if it's something you think you'll need, nobody here is going to write the code for you.

Comment: Ok thanks for advice. I often see people here answering with codes, so I thought someone would help. I ended up here because I couldn't fix on my own.